# Sharepoint column formatting with IF in href attribute

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I got this problem:

I got a column named "TrackingNumber". In this column I want to be able to click on the displayed Number.

The extra feature is, that in another column, there is the shipping company.

Now I would like to ensure that if, for example, "DHL" is entered as the shipping company in the "shipping" field, the DHL tracking link is used.

However, if another company is against in the "shipping" field, the other link should be used.

Right now I have the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "=if([$note.]=='1'),'https://mydhl.express.dhl/at/de/tracking.html#/results?id=6678310192', if([$note.title]=='2', 'https://www.post.at/en/sv/item-details?snr=1034598500013780802765'))",
    "target": "_blank"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the tracking number is no longer displayed for this version.

Could someone help me here, please?

Answer (score 0):

I can see there are some syntax error in your JSON code.

Assuming you have column with internal name as "shipping" which holds company name and this is simple column like single line of text or choice. You can build your if condition like:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "a",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "attributes": {
        "href": "=if([$shipping] == 'DHL', 'https://mydhl.express.dhl/at/de/tracking.html#/results?id=6678310192', if([$shipping] == 'Other Company', 'https://www.post.at/en/sv/item-details?snr=1034598500013780802765', '<default URL in case other conditions not met>'))",
        "target": "_blank"
    }
}
```

Make sure you use correct **internal name** of your field instead of shipping at `[$shipping]`. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Also, you can provide any default URL in place of `<default URL in case other conditions not met>`.

**Microsoft documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.
But it wont open if "DHL" is inserted in the shipping column.
If nothing is inserted in the shipping column, it opens the "default url"

U got a solution here as well?

Comment: What is the internal name and data type of your other column which holds shipping company?

Comment: name: shipping
Type: single line of text

Comment: ok, I have updated JSON code in my answer. there was some mistake in position of `)`. Try using new code

Comment: It works
Thank you very much!

Comment: Addition:

Now "DHL" works but the others dont

Comment: Ohh, can you please attach a screenshot if possible to see what it the issue for rows other than DHL?

Comment: Hi @Oliver does this answer your question? Is Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will be easier for others with similar question to find correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.